# how do I delete a volume from zpool - zfs

Tags: filesystem, zfs, storage, mass-storage

I created a zpool with 12 drives each 8TB using:

```
zpool create ch1 sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm
```

Then I **added 12 more 8TB drives** and wanted to add them to the zpool.
When I did **I only got 8TB of additional space** instead of the expected additional ~70TB using this command:

```
zpool add ch1 raidz sdn1 sdo1 sdp1 sdq1 sdr1 sds1 sdt1 sdu1 sdv1 sdw1 sdx1 sdy1
```

I wanted to do this:

```
zpool create ch2 sdb sdc sdd sde sdf sdg sdh sdi sdj sdk sdl sdm
```

Here is my zpool status:

```
hs@hs-farm:~$ zpool clear ch1
cannot clear errors for ch1: permission denied
hs@hs-farm:~$ sudo zpool clear ch1
hs@hs-farm:~$ zpool status
  pool: ch1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 44K in 0 days 00:00:00 with 0 errors on Thu Dec  2 13:59:03 2021
config:

    NAME                              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    ch1                               ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8f1d16d        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8e398b4        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c640250e        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8c85db3        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c9207ce8        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8d31803        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8c3b74c        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8e73721        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8e76055        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8d2d64f        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8e6b10a        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c62c8f66        ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-1                        ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8f38e11-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8f2fae4-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8d45a0e-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8c8bd98-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8f2fda8-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8dbc00a-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c7104af2-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8f62aad-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8db7231-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c9206973-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c8d2a7d4-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        wwn-0x5000c500c92175bc-part1  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

How do I get rid of raidz1-1 so I can create a new ch2 pool with my 12 new drives and use all the space.

BTW - I converted the zpool to use the drive ID's

Please help I need the storage - I'm new to Ubuntu - my first linux machine and loving the journey but feel totally stuck

Thanks!!!

[screenshot of my current zpool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZnb6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn how Ask Ubuntu works. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy `ch1` and re-create `ch1` & `ch2`.

If data are already on `pool`, move them with `send`/`recv`.

As mentioned in [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/zpool.8.html), `zpool remove` & `zpool detach` are not working with `raidz` *Vdevs*.

---

*Edit:*

Looking a bit further, this feature is available on freeBSD [since version 11.2](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool-features&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) with device_removal feature flag, which is available since [ZoL 0.8](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool-features&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html). Be aware that ZFS use the same base code between freeBSD and linux only since `openZFS 2.0`, so maybe this feature flag is not on the linux side on `ZoL 0.8`.

Comment: Thanks for the response

I have data on raidz1-0  that I don't have enough storage to move anywhere else.
I need to destroy raidz1-1 so that I can use it in a new pool - otherwise it's just wasted space.

Comment: what a shame - is there someone that can write this functionality if it doesn't exist as from my research I'm not the only person that is dealing with this. The answer I saw was this is to protect you but I don't need a baby sitter just need software to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Looking a bit further, this feature is available on freeBSD [since version 11.2](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=zpool-features&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) with `device_removal` feature flag, which is available [since ZoL 0.8](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/search?q=device_removal&type=code). Which ZFS version are you using ?

Comment: got the version, will try device removal next, and let you know how it goes - thanks!
#zpool version
zfs-0.8.3-1ubuntu12.13
zfs-kmod-2.0.2-1ubuntu5.4

Comment: '~$ sudo zpool remove ch1 raidz1-1
[sudo] password for hs: 
cannot remove raidz1-1: invalid config; all top-level vdevs must have the same sector size and not be raidz.'

Comment: Beware that ZFS use the same base code between freeBSD and linux only since `openZFS 2.0`, so maybe this feature flag is not on the linux side on `ZoL 0.8`.

Comment: I found this link and it looks like it is now possible but don't know how - is it just the 'remove' command?
see link[https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30256349#30273089]

Comment: see this article https://freebsdfoundation.org/blog/raid-z-expansion-feature-for-zfs/ not quite sure what to try here in my situation, any suggestions